# Format xml string in c#

Tags: xml

if anyone can help me on this, I would highly appreciate.

I have this xml string:

```
string xmlstring = "<ndActivityLog repositoryId=\"xxxxxxxx\" repositoryName=\"xxxxxxxx\" startDate=\"2017-10-10T00:00:00Z\" endDate=\"2017-10-10T23:59:59Z\">\n<activity date=\"2017-10-10T14:10:15\" name=\"change profile value\" host=\"xxxxxxxx\"><user id=\"xxxxxxxx\" name=\"xxxxxxxx\" memberType=\"I\" /><storageObject docId=\"xxxxxxxx\" name=\"xxxxxxxx\" size=\"11987\" fileExtension=\"docx\"><cabinet name=\"xxxxxxxx\">xxxxxxxx</cabinet><MatterC>xxxxxxxx</MatterC><ClientC>xxxxxxxx</ClientC><TypeofWork>Employment</TypeofWork></storageObject></activity>\r\n<activity date=\"2017-10-10T14:10:17\" name=\"open\" host=\"xxxxxxxx\"><user id=\"xxxxxxxx\" name=\"xxxxxxxx\" memberType=\"I\" /><storageObject docId=\"xxxxxxxx\" name=\"test11\" version=\"2\" size=\"11987\" fileExtension=\"docx\"><cabinet name=\"xxxxxxxx\">xxxxxxxx</cabinet><MatterC>xxxxxxxx</MatterC><ClientC>xxxxxxxx</ClientC><TypeofWork>Employment</TypeofWork></storageObject></activity>\r\n</ndActivityLog>"
```

As you can see in the string, I have all these extra / or /n or /r. How do I remove those character and convert my string to actual xml string.

Comment: whitespace is valid between XML nodes.  What is your real question?

Comment: `var xml = XElement.Parse(xmlstring);`

Comment: I am getting this error if I use this:{"Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1."}

Answer (score 0):

I think you should revisit the C# syntax. Your string `xmlstring` contains escaped characters to achieve the following:

- `\"`: Avoid compilation problems when using double quotes inside a string constant. To code a string like **this is "so cool"** in C#, you need to use the escape character for the double quotes: `coolstring = "this is \"so cool\""`.
- `\r` and `\n`: These are replacements for **carriage return** and **new line** control characters. If you would print your `xmlstring` to the console, it would not show up as a single line, but instead starting with a new line after each `\r\n` (not showing the control characters at all). Just as a side note: on Unix based systems, it is usually `\n` only.